# installation of django-admin-tools

Tags: django, django-admin-tools

I am new to django. I have downloaded the django-admin-tools and extraced it then I put it in the location "C:\Python27". Then I entered into the location "C:\Python27\django-admin-tools-0.5.1" and type the command

`python setup.py install`

but the error is

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What may be the solution ?

Comment: Should should never do that. [How to do link.](https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/)

I'm not a windows user. Linux is best for django development but still use pip and vitualenv for installion of python libraries and django libraries.
[django-admin-tool](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installing-django-admin-tools) is clearly doumented.

Comment: After the installation is complete, close the installer and select Start->Programs->Python 2.3->IDLE (Python GUI)

Comment: the problem is in the installation, the installation is not complete, then how to proceed after the installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the python on the environment variable list by following steps listed below.

Steps:-

- Go to Control Panel \System and Security\System
- Click on Change Settings
- Go to “Advance” tab
- Click on Environment Variables

for details :- [go here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6cde20/use-of-environment-variable-in-windows-8/)